# None Python error/bug?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, types

In Python you have the `None` singleton, which acts pretty oddly in certain circumstances:

```
>>> a = None
>>> type(a)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> isinstance(a,None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

So first off, `<type 'NoneType'>` displays that `None` is not a type, but that `NoneType` is. Yet when you run `isinstance(a,NoneType)`, it responds with an error: `NameError: name 'NoneType' is not defined`

Now, given this, if you have a function with an input default set to `None`, and need to check, you would do the following:

```
if variable is None:
    #do something
else:
    #do something
```

what is the reason that I cannot do the following instead:

```
if isinstance(variable,None): #or NoneType
    #do something
else:
    #do something
```

**I am just looking for a detailed explanation so I can better understand this**

Edit: good application

Lets say I wanted to use `isinstance` so that I can do something if `variable` is a variety of types, including `None`:

```
if isinstance(variable,(None,str,float)):
    #do something
```

Comment: `if variable == None` is anti-idiomatic Python. The standard way to do this test is by making use of the fact that `None` is a singleton: use `if variable is None` instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>> variable = None
>>> isinstance(variable,type(None))
True
>>> variable = True
>>> isinstance(variable,type(None))
False
```

[isinstance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) takes 2 arguments `isinstance(object, classinfo)` Here, by passing `None` you are setting `classinfo` to None, hence the error. You need pass in the type.

Answer (score 24):

`None` is not a type, it is the singleton instance itself - and the second argument of [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) must be a type, class or tuple of them. Hence, you need to use `NoneType` from [`types`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html).

```
from types import NoneType
print isinstance(None, NoneType)
print isinstance(None, (NoneType, str, float))
```

```
True
True
```

Although, I would often be inclined to replace `isinstance(x, (NoneType, str, float))` with `x is None or isinstance(x, (str, float))`.

Comment: Good answer and explanation, but I accepted karthikr because it did not require an import

Comment: @RyanSaxe It's alright, I forgive you. But if you plan on using `NoneType` a lot I would just import it from `types`. It seems unnecessary to call `type(None)` when you can easily access that value.

Comment: There is no longer a NoneType reference in types. You may use `NoneType = type(None)`

Comment: I like this answer because it normalizes my code, rather than handle the case of None differently

Answer (score 4):

`None` is the just a value of `types.NoneType`, it's not a type.

And the error is clear enough:

> TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a **class**, **type**, or tuple of
>   **classes** and **types**

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None):

> `None` is the sole **value** of `types.NoneType`. `None` is frequently used to represent
>   the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a
>   function.

You can use `types.NoneType`

```
>>> from types import NoneType
>>> isinstance(None, NoneType)
True
```

`is` operator  also works fine:

```
>>> a = None
>>> a is None
True
```

Answer (score 3):

`None` is a value(instance) and not a type. As the error message shows, `isinstance` expects the second argument to be a type.

The type of None is `type(None)`, or `Nonetype` if you import it (`from types import NoneType`)

Note: the idiomatic way to do the test is `variable is None`. Short and descriptive.