# The proper way to compare a variable with None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, standards, pep8

The commom way to test variable for `NoneType` is checking if it is referring to `None` singletone:

```
test_var is None
```

This approach is recommended as the only way to check for `None` according to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or
>   is not, never the equality operators.

Although sometimes I find the following test in different sources:

```
isinstance(test, type(None))
```

This way looks OK, but I can't quite figure out why simple and readable construction may be replaced with `isinstance`. Is it more useful for some cases or maybe referred to codestyle?

**UPD:** the only NoneType checking with `isinstance` I find really useful (so far):

```
isinstance(None, (NoneType, str, float))
```

Comment: Sounds like some programmer saw `NoneType` in an error message and decided to test for that without really understanding the problem. There's no benefit.

Comment: https://media1.tenor.com/images/fb50f8dd802894fce6bdafef59ddd84d/tenor.gif

Comment: You can also do `type(test) == None.__class__` and it'd work. The point being, a developer is free to achieve the solution in any way possible, it doesn't always mean that there is a reason behind it.

Comment: ok, but this way is mentioned even in some SO posts, so I really interested to clarify about its useless. Can't understand why the question is voted down, btw.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is the right one hahaha: https://giphy.com/gifs/the-office-no-michael-scott-ToMjGpx9F5ktZw8qPUQ

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko: I can't find any other Stack Overflow post that uses that method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553285/determining-a-variables-type-is-nonetype-in-python
However, the accepted answer mentioned `is` as prefered way

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko It is becoming too mainstream: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198511/2430448

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is **never** a reason to use that construct.

You can't subclass `NoneType`. The only object that would ever pass that test is the `None` singleton. That line was probably written by someone that didn't know this and thought they needed to test for subclasses too.